# WSO2 API Manager 1.6 Exception running Youtube sample

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm trying to run the YoutubeFeeds sample present in the package 1.6 of WSO2 API Manager. I performed, as mentioned in the Product Documentation, the following steps:

1. executed "ant" command in the /CARBON_HOME/bin directory --> OK
2. executed "ant" command in the /CARBON_HOME/samples/Data directory --> OK
3. started the API Manager server
4. executed "APIPopulator.bat" in the /CARBON_HOME/samples/YoutubeFeeds directory --> OK
5. executed the command curl -H **"**Authorization: Bearer " http://:8280/youtube/1.0.0/most_viewed**"**

After executed the step 5, if I have configured "Thrift" as authentication protocol  between API GW and API Key Manager I got the following error : **Error while accessing backend services for API key validation**. It seems that are some problems regarding the Key validation check. I tried to solve the issue but with no results.

So after that I tried to switch with "WSClient" authentication protocol and in this case I got a 202 HTTP return Code, that means: the request has been accepted but it has not been completed. In this way the request is accepted but i don't get any response.

P.S.: The API Manager is running on the Default Ports (Offset port is 0)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you had with Thrift can happen if you have multiple network interfaces. The interface to which it would get bound cannot be specified in the config. What you can do is find the correct interface Thrift gets started on and specify that IP in:

```
<ThriftServerHost>127.0.0.1</ThriftServerHost>
```

There are two such elements and please note that you have to change them both.

Comment: I have configured **<ThriftServerHost>** as you mentioned, but now I'm facing another Exception: [2014-03-26 14:38:35,202] **ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception**
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidator.java:385)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.doGetAPIInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:240)...